# Recursive selection of categories

Tags: sql, postgresql, recursion

In my database I have the following table:

```
Category: {[Name: VarChar, TopCategory: VarChar]}
```

The Table has the following contents:

[image: Contents of the Table]

Now I need to get all names from all subcategories of the category `Computer Science` using the `with-clause` in a recursive statement.
This has to be done using SQL, no PHP or other programming language.

All subcategories means not only the direct decendants but also in this case `C++` and `Java`
How do I do this?

What I do have so far:

```
SELECT name FROM category WHERE (topcategory = 'Computer Science')
```

Comment: do you want the values to be separated by a comma?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here we go:

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte_t1 (name, topcategory, Level)
AS
(
SELECT name, topcategory, 0 AS Level
FROM Category
WHERE topcategory = N'ComputerScience'
UNION ALL
SELECT t1.name, t1.topcategory, Level + 1
FROM Category t1, cte_t1 ctet1
WHERE ctet1.name= t1.topcategory
)
SELECT Level, topcategory, name
FROM cte_t1
```

Comment: why is it not useful? You will get the recursive results that you are not getting with the answer from John Woo

Comment: Now it is. I downvoted it when it was a copy'n'paste from some example that you didn't even bother to adapt, fix or test.

Comment: Note that materialized path ( extension ltree ) can be used for that kind of purpose and do nested categories easily and fast.

Comment: Thank You, Michael. I didn't copy and paste from nowhere but my own SQL Server Editor. I created a table variable called @table1 with fields category and parent. I noticed I didn't correctly translated the names when posting the answer and edited it afterwards. But I designed the table, wrote the query and tested the results. Just with my own dummy names.

Answer (score 0):

if your database is oracle, you can try it ([sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/13c64/11)):

```
select * from category 
  start with name = 'Computer Science'
connect by prior name = top_category
```